# Como forzar al pedir un dato decimal que el usuario lo ingrese con comas para que no me salte este error

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SOy nuevo en java y estoy trabajando un proyecto y tengo un problema Cuando creo mi codigo y le pido al usuario ingresar un numero decimal necesito que lo ingrese con comas por ejemplo 1,2 pero cuando lo compilo me marca este error... Hay una forma de poner algo en el codigo para que funcione con decimal y no con puntos

Comment: Debes saber que en general los lenguajes de programación interpretan el punto como signo separador decimal en lugar de la coma.

Comment: Ingresalo como string, reemplaza las comas y puntos, convierte a punto flotante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error `InputMismatchException` dice la documentación que es lanzado por el `Scanner` cuando el valor dado, no coincide con el valor esperado.

Por ejemplo espera un valor **decimal** y le estas dando un **texto**. (ya que no reconoce las comas).

Podes hacer la prueba intentando crear una variable
`float decimal = 1,3;` esto tirara error, y cualquier IDE te lo advertiría.

Creo que lo que esta pasando aquí, es que el sistema esta usando la configuración regional para difinir si usa "." o ","

Cree un programa y le pedía al Scanner un Float, pero yo lo escribía con "," y me lo aceptaba, pero cuando lo escribía con "." me daba el error`InputMismatchException`. (caso contrario al tuyo)

Como dije antes, creo que esto depende de cada sistema en el que se esta ejecutando o de otros factores.

El ejemplo que utilice para solucionar porque me daba error:

```
public Main() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite un numero decimal: ");
    
    String text = scanner.nextLine().replace(",", ".");
    float number = Float.parseFloat(text);
    
    // hacer cálculos con ese numero...
    
    scanner.close(); // cerrar el Scanner
}
```

Lo podes corregir pidiendo un texto y remplazar las comas por puntos para luego convertirlo a decimal.

Ahora funciona en cualquiera de los casos, ya que al final lo obtiene con puntos, como mencione antes Java usa puntos para las variables.

Comment: Gacias amigo eres grande me funciono, ya me estaba estresando gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo de Entrada de datos de parte de un Usuario

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrompUser
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner prompt_value = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\n\nEnter a number: ");

        float p_data = prompt_value.nextFloat();


        System.out.println(p_data);
        
    }

}
```

Salida de Codigo

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2496)
        at PrompUser.main(PrompUser.java:13)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimado compañero, lo que creo que te puede estar ocurriendo es tan solo un pequeño error al momento de compilar el script, yo intente realizar un codigo de prueba donde solicito un data al usuario y lo transformo en decimal, sin embargo como puedes apreciar, de igual manera que a ti, me aparecio el error **InputMismatchException**, por lo que intente nuevamente el compilar, y de esa forma funciono la solicituda creada en el script.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo ¡

Answer (score 0):

Complementando la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/469246/193364) de @JFrame.
Si estas ingresando los decimales con `,` seguramente es porque en tu país se ingresa con ese símbolo, entonces la manera que muestres los decimales también deben ser con `,`
Entonces necesitas usar `DecimalFormatSymbols` para cambiar por el símbolo que te interesa. Ejemplo

```
        DecimalFormatSymbols simbolos = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        simbolos.setDecimalSeparator(',');  //Aquí ponemos en símbolo con el cual mostramos los decimales en este caso es la ","
        DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("####.##",simbolos); //Para redondear los decimales a 2 dígitos
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Ingrese un numero decimal : ");
        String text = leer.nextLine().replace(",", ".");
        float number = Float.parseFloat(text);
        
        System.out.println ("El decimal formateado es: "+formateador.format(number));
```

Al ejecutar el programa tendremos

```
Ingrese un numero decimal : 1,5899
El decimal formateado es: 1,59
```